# How to properly validate date to a specific format?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date, date-formatting

I need to validate the date format of my field as my db only access this (Y-m-d) format.

Thus, I need to be able to convert any other date format to that of this format. 
One problem I have is that depending on which browser I use the date format in my input date field change. For example current firefox browser date format is mm/dd/yyyy but I need it for change to (Y-m-d).

my form

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="DateField">Age: </label>
       <input type="date" class="form-control" id='DateField' name="date" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" size="10" minlength="6" maxlength="10" required/>
 </div>
```

I looking to be able to covert any of those format 
(Y/m/d, d/m/Y, m/d/Y, d-m-Y, m-d-Y, Y.m.d, d.m.Y, m.d.Y)  to that of (Y-m-d)

```
$format = "d-m-Y";
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $_POST['DateField'])->format('Y-m-d'); //here getting error msg

        $date_errors = DateTime::getLastErrors();
        if($date_errors['warning_count'] + $date_errors['error_count'] > 0) {
         // createFromFormat returns false if the format is invalid;
            echo 'Date format is incorrect e.g Y-m-d';
            exit();
        }
```

One way for me to solve it was to use the **jquery datepicker** but it does not work in **firefox 57** onward... (yes I try to change the input field type="date" to that type="text" but still does not work...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var datefield = document.createElement("input");
    datefield.setAttribute("type", "date");
    if (datefield.type !== "date"){ //if browser doesn't support input type="date", load files for jQuery UI Date Picker
        document.write('<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/dot-luv/jquery-ui.css " rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />\n');
        document.write('<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"><\/script>');

    }

</script>

<script>
    $(function(){
        if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) { //if browser doesn't support input type="date", initialize date picker widget:
        // If not native HTML5 support, fallback to jQuery datePicker

            $('input[type=date]').datepicker({
                // Consistent format with the HTML5 picker
                    dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
                    maxDate: 0
                },
                // Localization
                $.datepicker.regional['it']

            );
        }
    });
</script>
```

Error msg:  Call to a member function format() on boolean
Why does the jquery datepicker not working in firefox 57

Comment: Have you considered the Moment.js library? It's very simple and immensely helpful https://momentjs.com/

Comment: how do I use it... I just put it in my php file?

Comment: You might wanna take a look at what the browser send to server. Although displayed differently chrome does send it it in Y-m-d format for input type date

Comment: for chrome its d-m-Y(13-Jan-20XX) and for firefox(which I'm using) its mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Check the dev tools. And check (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome)

Comment: @JOnathaFlint You would use Moment.js on the front-end and then pass back the formatted date to your PHP

Comment: frz did you not see that I wrote that even when I change the input type to text it(jquery datepicker) still does not work

Comment: As @frz3993 says, what you see in the browser and what gets sent to the server can be different - check the actual POST data in the browser dev tools.  You will probably need to accept the date in a number of formats, parse, and convert to your desired Y-m-d ... another problem is your `d/m/Y, m/d/Y` requirement -- There is _no way_ to tell if 2/3/2018 is d/m/Y or m/d/Y (Feb 3 or Mar 2?) you can only do a best-guess based on the user's Locale, or ask them which they mean. Also, with the jQuery datepicker you can set the `dateFormat` to what you'd like.

Comment: If you want to reformat a date string, probably the worst way is to turn it into a date then turn it back into a string. Consider just reformatting the string. To correctly parse a date string, it is essential to know the format, otherwise you're leaving it to chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d'){
    $v = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $v && $v->format($format) == $date;
}
var_dump(validateDate('2000-02-20', 'Y-m-d')); //true
var_dump(validateDate('20-02-2000', 'Y-m-d')); //false
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtotime` for this. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

`$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['DateField']));`

Comment: I opened the https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ with Firefox and it is works for me

Comment: may that be related to z-index issue?

Comment: `if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date)` <-- this part of your code. Firefox support date type that's why jquery ui data picker is not attached.

Comment: isnt there a way so that even if the browser support input type=date, make jquery datepicker overtake it?

Comment: you can use `type="text"` and remove the if condition